# How to develop a scroll bar for the center content

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js

I am new to VueJS. I am developing an application using Vue and Bootstrap. The page is broken down into a left sidebar, a top navbar, a center view, and a right sidebar, like this:

[image]

I am looking to develop an a scrollbar so that only the center content is scrollable

Here is the code:

```js
import GridView from 'src/components/Dashboard/Views/GridView.vue'
  import ListView from 'src/components/Dashboard/Views/ListView.vue'
  import DetailsView from 'src/components/Dashboard/Views/DetailsView.vue'

  export default {
    methods:{

      changeView(){
        if(this.gridView === true){
          this.gridView = false;
        }
        else if(this.gridView === false){
          this.gridView = true;
        }
      },

      openDetailsSection() {
        if(this.detailsSectionOpen === false){
          this.detailsSectionOpen = true;
        }

        this.$nextTick(() => {
          const detailsSection = document.getElementById("details");
          const showSection = document.getElementById("show");
          
          showSection.style.width = "80%";
          
          // showSection.classList.remove("col-xl-12", "col-md-6");
        })
      },

      closeDetailsSection(){
        if(detailsSectionOpen === true){
          detailsSectionOpen = false;
        }
        const detailsSection = document.getElementById("details");
        const showSection = document.getElementById("show");
        detailsSection.classList.remove("col-xl-3");
        showSection.classList.remove("col-xl-9", "col-md-6");
        showSection.classList.add("col-xl-12", "col-md-6");
        
        // Remove info button
        const infoButton = document.getElementById('infoButton');
        if (infoButton) {
          infoButton.parentNode.removeChild(infoButton);
        }
      },
    },

    data(){
      return {

        detailsSectionOpen: false,

        gridView: true,

        shared: false
       
      }
    },

    components: {
      ListView,
      GridView,
      DetailsView
    },

    
    mounted(){
      
      let folders = document.getElementsByClassName('folder-rectangle');      
      folders = Array.from(folders);
      folders.forEach((folder) => folder.addEventListener('click', this.showButton));
      
    }
  }
```

```css
.context-menu-item:hover {
    background-color: #E91E63 !important;
  }

  .plus-circle-btn{
    font-size: 70px;
    color: #E91E63;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  li .btn:hover{
    color: #E91E63;
  }

  .details-ul li{
    width: 261px;
    height: 29px;
    color: #424242;
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro';
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 1px;
    padding: 5px;
  }
  .color{
    background-color: #DCF3FD;
  }

  #context-menu-icon{
    color: #424242;
  }

  .header-rectangle {
    height: 155px; 
    background: #F5F5F5; 
    border: 1px solid #E0E0E0; 
    border-radius: 0px;
    border-bottom: none;
  }

  .footer-rectangle {  
    height: 65px; 
    background: #FAFAFA;
    border: 1px solid #E0E0E0; 
    border-radius: 0px;
    vertical-align:middle; text-align:center;
  }

  #image { 
    height: 16px; 
    border: 0px;
    color: #878D99;
  }

  .file-name-style{
    height: 26px; 
    color: #424242; 
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro'; 
    font-size: 15px; 
    font-weight: normal; 
    font-style: normal; 
    text-decoration: none; 
    text-align: left;
    padding: 5px 15px;
  }

  .file-size-style{
    height: 26px; 
    color: #9E9E9E; 
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro'; 
    font-size: 12px; 
    text-align: left; 
    line-height: 1px;
    padding: 10px 15px;
  }

  .breadcrumb-hr {
    -moz-border-bottom-colors: none;
    -moz-border-image: none;
    -moz-border-left-colors: none;
    -moz-border-right-colors: none;
    -moz-border-top-colors: none;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    border: 1px solid #BDBDBD;
    margin-top: 0px;
    border-top-width: 0px;
  }

  .breadcrumb-hr-details {
    -moz-border-bottom-colors: none;
    -moz-border-image: none;
    -moz-border-left-colors: none;
    -moz-border-right-colors: none;
    -moz-border-top-colors: none;
    border: 1px solid #BDBDBD;
    margin-top: 0px;
    border-top-width: 0px;
  }

  .details-section-hr{
    -moz-border-bottom-colors: none;
    -moz-border-image: none;
    -moz-border-left-colors: none;
    -moz-border-right-colors: none;
    -moz-border-top-colors: none;
    
    border: 1px solid #BDBDBD;
    margin-top: 0px;
    border-top-width: 0px;
  }

  .folder-rectangle {
    height: 63px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid rgb(189, 189, 189);
    border-radius: 0px;
  }

  .folder-selected {
    background: #DCF3FD; 
    border: 1px solid #BDBDBD; 
    border-radius: 0px; 
    box-shadow:0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(3,169,244,1)
  }

  .file-selected {
    height: 63px; 
    background: #DCF3FD; 
    border: 1px solid #BDBDBD; 
    border-radius: 0px; 
    box-shadow:0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(3,169,244,1)
  }

  #folder-image{ 
    width: 29px; 
    height: 20px;
    color: #878D99;
    font-size: 30px;
  }

  .context-menu{  
    width: 197px; 
    height: 400px;
    background: #FFFFFF; 
    border: 1px solid #FFFFFF; 
    border-radius: 5px; 
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #333; 
  }

  .context-menu-span{
    padding-left: 10px;
    color: #424242;
  }

  .btn{
    background-color: none;
    border: none;
    color: grey;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .folder-name-style{
    text-align: left;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-top: 13px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    color: #424242; 
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro'; 
    font-size: 15px; 
    font-weight: normal; 
    font-style: normal; 
    text-decoration: none;
    
  }

  .folder-size-style{
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 13px;
    margin-top: 8px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    color: #9E9E9E;
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
  }

  #no-padding{
    padding: 0px;
  }
  
  #grid-view{
    overflow-y: scroll;
  }

  #grid-view::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 1em;
  }
 
  #grid-view::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
      -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  }
  
  #grid-view::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: darkgrey;
    outline: 1px solid slategrey;
  }
```

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="content" style="padding-top: 3px;" id="show">

      <div class="container-fluid">

        <ol class="breadcrumb" id="topButtons" style="display: flex;width: 100%;padding: 0rem 1rem;background-color: transparent;margin-bottom: 0px;">
          <li class="breadcrumb-item active" style="margin-right: auto; margin-left: 0px; padding-top: 13px; color: #424242; 
              font-family: 'Source Sans Pro'; 
              font-size: 18px; 
              font-weight: normal; 
              font-style: normal; 
              text-decoration: none; 
              text-align: left;">
              Files
          </li> 
          <li class="pull-right">
            <button class="btn">
              <i class="fa fa-sort-amount-asc">
              </i>
            </button>
          </li> 
          <li class="pull-right">
            <button v-if="gridView === false" @click="changeView" class="btn">
              <i class="fa fa-th-large"></i>
            </button>
            <button v-if="gridView === true" @click="changeView" class="btn">
              <i class="fa fa-list-ul">
              </i>
            </button>
            <button v-if="!detailsSectionOpen" class="btn" id="infoButton" @click="openDetailsSection">
              <i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i>
            </button>
          </li>
        </ol>

        <!-- Line break -->
        <hr class="breadcrumb-hr">

        <div>
          <!-- Grid view secation begins here -->
          <grid-view v-if="gridView === true" :folders="folders" :recentFiles="recentFiles" id="grid-view" >
          </grid-view>

          <!-- List View section begins here -->
          <list-view v-if="gridView === false" :folders="folders" :recentFiles="recentFiles">
          </list-view>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <details-view v-if="detailsSectionOpen" id="details"></details-view>
  </div>
</template>
```

I am trying to develop a scrollbar for the id="show", such that the content between the 2 bars is scrollable, but I am unable to so so.

Can someone please help me out here? I'd really appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

set a fixed `height` and use the `overflow-y`, a example:

```
#show {
    height: 600px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but how do I access the scrollbar element? I need to style it

Comment: it's simple, just edit some properties of the scrollbar, I do not put here because it is more of a property, but I leave [a simple example in w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_scrollbar.asp)

Comment: Thanks! I have created the scrollbar, but, I am unable to scroll it although I have set overflow-y:scroll. Can you please tell me how I can get it scrollable? I have modified the above code. Thanks!

Comment: I think your question is solved and you are having another problem, I advise you to ask another question for this since maybe the problem is no longer CSS and HTML, maybe something in the framework in question is blocking the correct behavior of css and in that I I can not help you
I made an example for you to see how it works [CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/dever/pen/wOWqLz)